# Monitor Is No Longer Recognized By PC

Tags: graphics-card

A few days ago, something happened with my Skytech Chronos Mini, where my monitor, my keyboard, and my mouse no longer worked with it.  It still powers on, and the usb and hdmi ports still work.  But my monitor and thumb drives no longer work with my tower.  I replaced the graphics card, and I was very careful to reinstall it correctly.  I checked my ram stick and cleaned it, making sure to reinstall it correctly.  Still nothing.  Could it be that the PCIE power cable could be at fault?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I suggest taking it to a repair-shop.

Comment: Please explain how you can tell that the and the USB and HDMI ports still work given that you cannot get your monitor (HDMI?), nor your keyboard and mouse (USB?) to work.

Comment: “Could it be that the PCIE power cable could be at fault?” - Is the cable visual damaged? Even it was damaged it would not explain the reason unrelated USB devices stopped working. How did you determine the HDMI ports work if your monitor wasn’t working